# Can't debugging Type Script in chrome with node js

Tags: node.js, debugging, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I have three files in `./`

- main.ts
- main.js
- main.js.map

I am doing `node inspect-brk ./main.js`,
opening chrome, typing `chrome://inspect`

Debugger is in the pause state.
I press `F10` to make a step.
The problem is that chrome dev tools can't see `ts` file.
All settings in chrome that allows to see source maps are settled.
Chrome writes that `Source Map detected` and instructs me to add associated files in tree.
I have tried to add `main.ts` in workspace but chrome don't want to jump into it.

What do I have to do to walk through `ts` code?

```
Node.js version is v8.0.0 
Chrome 59.0.3071.86
Type Script 2.3
```